# Changing nickname in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

So I've looked at a fair few forum posts and can't find something fitting my code.

I'm trying to do something like this...

```
          case "setnick":
         if (args[1]) {
            if (message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_NICKNAMES")) {
                if (message.member.hasPermission("CHANGE_NICKNAME"))
                  message.member.setNickname(args[1])
                  else message.channel.send("You do not have the permissions! **(CHANGE_NICKNAME)**")
            } 
             else message.channel.send("The bot does not have the permissions! **(MANAGE_NICKNAMES)**")
         }
          else message.channel.send("There's no argument to set your nickname too! **Eg. f!setnick NICKNAME**")
          break;
```

So it checks if there is a argument like

```
f!setnick NICKNAME
```

Then checks if the bot has permission MANAGE_NICKNAMES

if it doesn't it sends a chat message.

And it then checks for if the user has the permission CHANGE_NICKNAME
so i'm wondering why its not working.

Any reason why?

Answer (score 1):

**Have you tried checking if it works on other users besides yourself?** Bots can not do administrator commands (like change someone's nickname) if you are higher/the same in the hierarchy than it, and seeing the owner is the ultimate power it is probably returning a permission error.

Try catching it and see what the error is

```
message.member.setNickname(args[1]).catch(e=>console.log(e))
```

if it returns DiscordAPIError: Privilege is too low... then my theory is correct. It should work for lower users.

Comment: It gives that error but the rank the bot has is higher than me!

Comment: Owner of the server overwrites any roles. Owner is always the highest

Answer (score 0):

`message.member.me` doesn't get the bot's user, it gets the user sending the message. Try `message.guild.members.find("id", client.user.id).hasPermission("MANAGE_NICKNAMES")`